# How do I design a algorithm to predict the outcome of a game with both players playing optimally?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Currently, I am looking for a recursive solution to predict the outcome of a game with both players playing optimally. The game is played between two players.

I am given a sequence of numbers in the form of an array and always want to draw a number from one of the edge sides (i.e. start or end of the array). Depending on which player's turn it is, the points are credited and it is the next player's turn. This player now also chooses a number, which is at the edge of the number array. At the end the player with the larger sum has won.

In the graphic all possible game courses for four starting numbers are visualized in a binary tree. I am now wondering how to design a recursive algorithm that takes all these possible combinations into account and finally returns the score of the winning player if both players play optimally.

[image: Binary-Tree: level 1 (3592), level 2 (359;952),(35,59;95,52), level 3 (3,5;5,9. 9,5;5,2)]

Comment: This question does not contain enough specifics for others to provide helpful answers. Take a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if you are talking about [nim game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim), let me know so I can help you with.

Comment: There's n(n+1)/2 game states, and you can use dynamic programming to compute the value of each state.

Comment: You might be interested in the [minimax algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax#Minimax_algorithm_with_alternate_moves). If you look at the last branching point before a leaf, it's relatively obvious which move the player will make; mark the result of the best move on the corresponding node. Then do that for the second-to-last branching points; etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about optimal game results I assume that the player always chooses the highest number.

You will need to add *deque* pakages

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
```

Here you have a method that gives an array with the player A and player B results.

```
private static int[] optimalGameResults(int[] board) {
        boolean turnA=true;
        int sumA=0,sumB=0;
        Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
        for (int n: board) {
            deque.offer(n);
        }
        while (deque.size()>0){
            if(turnA){
                sumA = sumOptimal(sumA, deque);
                turnA=false;
            }else{
                sumB = sumOptimal(sumB, deque);
                turnA=true;
            }
        }
        int[] abResults={sumA,sumB};
        return abResults;
    }
```

It also needs an additional method to know which value remove (optimization)

```
private static int sumOptimal(int sum, Deque<Integer> deque) {
        if(deque.getFirst()> deque.getLast()){
            sum += deque.removeFirst();
        }else {
            sum += deque.removeLast();
        }
        return sum;
    }
```